# ¿Cómo seleccionar los años con datos completos (365 y 366 días), desde un marco de datos?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

Los contextualizo, tengo un dataframe con con 7 variables (Fecha, Pcp, Tmax, Tmin, Year, Mes, Día), con 12,746 observaciones días de precipitación y temperatura minima y máxima, y también cuenta con el año, el mes y el día, divididos en columnas, en dicho data frame se encuentran datos faltantes y los que quiero hacer es seleccionar los años que esten compleots osea que tengan 365 y 366 días con datos completos, y hacer otra data frame. Aquí pongo el código:

```
library(tseries);
library(astsa);
library(forecast);
library(tidyverse);
library(lubridate);
library(foreign);
library(quantmod);
library(sqldf)
library(compare);
library(readtext);
library(datos);
library(openxlsx) # loads library and doesn't require Java installed
#install.packages("gganimate")
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr);
library(memisc);
library(gifski)
library(DataExplorer)
library(dplyr)
# install.packages("plyr");

rm(list = ls())

# Asignar la ruta de trabja
getwd();
setwd("D:/Final_Irrn651/Conagua");
getwd();


#  Leer los archivos con extensi?n .txt
files <- list.files(pattern = ".*.txt");

# Leer los archivos .txt, darles formato y guardarlos en la variable de datos
datos <- read.fwf(files, widths = c(10, 7, 7, 7, 7),
         skip = 19,
         col.names = c("Fecha", "Prec (mm)", "Evap (mm)",
                       "Tmax (?C)", "Tmin (?C)"))

# Eliminar la ultima columna
datos <- datos[-11482,]


# Aplicar un ciclo for para cambiar el fromato a fecha de la primera columna
# para toda la lista
for (i in 1:length(datos)){
  datos$Fecha <- as.Date(datos$Fecha, "%d/%m/%Y")
  datos$Prec..mm. <- as.numeric(datos$Prec..mm.)
  datos$Tmin...C. <- as.numeric(datos$Tmin...C.)
  datos$Tmax...C. <- as.numeric(datos$Tmax...C.)
  datos$Evap..mm. <- as.numeric(datos$Tmax...C.)
}

# Seleccionar solo los columna de Fecha, Prec..mm.,Tmax...C., Tmin...C.
datos_0 <- dplyr::select(datos, Fecha, Prec..mm.,Tmax...C., Tmin...C.)

# Agregar el año, el mes y el día al data frame
for (i in 1:length(datos_0)){
  datos_0$Ano <- as.numeric(format(datos_0$Fecha,'%Y'));
  datos_0$mes <- as.numeric(format(datos_0$Fecha,'%m'));
  datos_0$dia <- as.numeric(format(datos_0$Fecha,'%d'));
}

# Identificar la fecha mas antigua
print(min(datos_0$Fecha, na.rm = TRUE))

# Identificar la fecha mas antigua
print(max(datos_0$Fecha, na.rm = TRUE))


# Guardar cada fecha en un vector
inicio <- as.Date(min(datos_0$Fecha, na.rm = TRUE))
fin <- as.Date(max(datos_0$Fecha, na.rm = TRUE))


# Agregar los datos de inicio y final y 
# que avance por día
datos_1 <- group_by(datos_0) %>%
  complete(Fecha = seq(min(inicio),
                       max(fin), by = "1 day"),
           fill = list("na"));

# Verificar los NA en las columnas
datos_1 %>% map_dbl(.f = function(x){sum(is.na(x))})

# Graficar los NA por columna
plot_missing(
  data    = datos_1, 
  title   = "Porcentaje de valores Faltantes por variable",
  ggtheme = theme_bw(),
  theme_config = list(legend.position = "none")
)
```

Estoy intentado lo siguiente:

```
# Renombrar las columnas
names(datos_1)<- c("Fecha", "Pcp", "Tmax", "Tmin", "Year", 
                "Mes", "Dia");

# Ver los años que tienen datos completos (365 a 366 dias)
years <- as.data.frame(table(datos_1$Year));

# Filtrar los años >= 365 días
filtro_years <- years[years$Freq >= 365,] 

# Guardar en un vector con los años con >= 365 días
years_filtro = c(1977:1979, 1983:1986, 1989:1991, 1995:1997, 2001, 2005, 2007:2010)

# Seleccionar con base a years_filtro, los años completos del data frame
datos_3 <- datos_1[datos_1$Year == years_filtro & datos_1$Dia == c(1:31), ]
```

Con el código anterior no consigo filtrar los años con datos completos (>= 365), si alguien me pudiera orientar con esto.

[Adjunto base de datos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IY4rCknDcmlNZh_ybGSbOHSHj8kGoGTq/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Conceptualmente tenemos que: (1) calcular la cantidad de días que tiene cada año del universo de las observaciones (2) Contar la cantidad de días reales por año (3) filtrar observaciones de años cuya cantidad de días sea igual al de las observaciones.

Para empezar necesitamos definir dos funciones, podríamos recurrir a algún paquete como `lubridate`, pero lo cierto que son mu sencillas, necesitamos una para obtener el año dado una fecha y otra para saber si el año es bisiesto:

```
year <- function(x) {as.POSIXlt(x)$year + 1900}
leap_year <- function(year) {
  return(ifelse((year %%4 == 0 & year %%100 != 0) | year %%400 == 0, TRUE, FALSE))
}
```

Antes que nada, hay que transformar la fecha en un fecha real, con esto, nos va a resultar cómodo contar con el año en cada observación:

```
datos$Fecha <- as.Date(datos$Fecha, format = '%d/%m/%Y')
datos %>% 
  mutate(año = year(Fecha)) -> datos
```

Ahora podemos generar el conjunto de años completos:

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(año) %>% 
  summarise(dias_año = first(if_else(leap_year(año), 366, 365)),
            dias_reales = n()) %>% 
  filter(dias_año == dias_reales) %>% 
  select(año) -> años_completos
```

Y por último para filtrar los datos, simplemente haremos un `inner join` sobre la lista de años completos:

```
datos %>% 
  inner_join(años_completos,
             by="año")
```

Fuentes:

- [How to account for leap years?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52067205/6836377)
- [Count days per year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9466219/6836377)

Comment: Patricio Moracho, muchas gracias funciono perfectamente, ahora ya tengo los años completos en un data frame. Muchas gracias.